# Convert Existing iOS App to framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

I have an existing project.So I want to convert my **existing iOS app to a framework** without creating a new framework separately and copy files from my existing app.Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Create `Cocoa touch framework` to your same project, and go to all the files and add them into your framework's target as well using `file inspector`.(i.e. First tab of right `Utilities` bar).

Comment: Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

Create the framework, reference it into your app, move the necessary files into the framework. It might be longer than converting, if it is possible, but you will have a view about what needs really to be there.